# Access common services on Swiggy with APIs

Tags: java, rest

How can I register and get the authentication token for Swiggy via API?

I tried using api-urls available online to register as a user and get an authentication token, however, I was unable to achieve it.

I am expecting to share the process to register and get an Authentication token and know if we can explore the services that can be accessed with API calls.